# Should I return URLs related to an item in my response

Tags: rest, api

In my API I should return a list of products. In the client (browser) the user can add this products to a cart, increasing, decreasing, or remove this a product from the cart.

In my response with the products list should I put the URLs actions like this:

```
{
   "alias": 'aliasValue',
   "removeUrl": 'domain/product/alias/',
   "increaseUrl": 'domain/product/alias/increase/',
   "decreaseUrl": 'domain/product/alias/decrease/',
   ...
}
```

Is this a good practice, I've searched for this but the only thing that I found about URL and API is about the URL structures.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm really having problem with the code indentation, I'm putting the four spaces as required but it's not working

Comment: You need a newline before the code block. Fixed it for ya. :)

Comment: @ErickStein Thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against reinventing the wheel. There are [many ways](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) to use [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) in your API.

Consider, for example, the [HAL (Hypertext Application Language)](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) approach, where you have a `_links` property:

```json
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://example.com/api/books/1"
    }
  },
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Hypermedia as First-Class Citizen"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve as a name **HATEOAS** that stands for Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State.

So if you search for it you will find a lot of formats:

- JSON-LD
- HAL
- SIREN
- ION
- JSON API
- Spring
- Ripozo

Source: https://nordicapis.com/tools-to-make-hateoas-compliance-easier/

Answer (score 1):

As REST is just a generatlization of the browsable Web we all know, you can basically apply the same concepts as if you'd implement your system for the browser. In short, a server should provide a client with all the necessary information the client will need to make educated decisions which resources to invoke next.

In a browser-based Web application the interaction model could be similar to invoking the start page, seeing a section in the response that is of interest to you, click a link to learn further details. The next page might list some items where you are provided with further controls to modify this list, i.e. add a new item, remove one and so forth. Upon clicking some "add" button a form is presented to you which teaches you what fields a request should contain and also where this request should be sent to, even if it might not be visible to you. In the back the browser will take care of that for you. The jumping point here is, the server is actually feeding the client with any information needed to proceed through his task, whether it is the choice of available links to explore or the presentation of some guidelines on how a request should look like.

In order to determine whether a link is of interest to a client a server will use meaningful link relation names "attached" to URIs a client should use instead of parsing and interpreting URIs. This allows a server to change URIs anytime without affecting a client. Fielding mentioned the following in one of his blogposts:

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

In addtion to that REST APIs shouldn't have [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) meaningful to clients as this basically couples the client tightly to the API itself and will lead to failures if the serve ever changes anything in regards to the response returned. Instead content-type negotiation should be used in order to let client and server negotiate about the actual representation format used.

A media type defines the processing rules of some payload that is received for a certain `Content-Type` HTTP header. These rules define both syntax as well as semantics of the document. Servers in a REST architecture are i.e. allowed to reject any messages sent for a certain content type if the rules outlined in the media type are [violated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

While the focus on media-types doesn't prevent changes done to the representations received completly, it still is useful in helping to decouple clients from servers further and reduce out-of-band information needed in order to interact with the service. Instead of coupling a client directly to the API, both couple to the media-type actually, and there might be multiple media types they actually couple to. If there ever needs to be a change done to a media-type you can easily introduce a new media type or, similar to HTML, specify within the media-type how backwards compatibility is achived.

In regards to prior, out-of-band information requirements, which REST doesn't completly remove, Fielding stated

> Of course the client has prior knowledge. Every protocol, every media type definition, every URI scheme, and every link relationship type constitutes prior knowledge that the client must know (or learn) in order to make use of that knowledge. REST doesn’t eliminate the need for a clue. What REST does is concentrate that need for prior knowledge into readily standardizable forms. That is the essential distinction between data-oriented and control-oriented integration. ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-742))

As REST isn't a focus on one single aspect but a conglomeration of all of the aspects mentioned above, your actual question should be tackled from multiple angles.

First, either use existing link relations, i.e. administered by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or other [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values), define new ones which you should register with IANA at best or use some semantic web related tags like [schema.org](https://schema.org). I.e. if you have collections then `next`, `prev`, `first` and `last` are pretty meaningful (and already registered at IANA)  for pagination or `item` for a decicated item within the list. This collection might have been returned previously as `collection` before or specified by the respective item in order to go back to the previous collection. If somethin like an add or edit should be done a link-relation like `edit-form` can teach the client that the URI will return some kind of form that will tell the client how a request to the API will need to look like.

Next, as basic JSON isn't that great in terms of providing help to a client, as all it does is define the syntactical structure of a document but lack support of given the elements meaning, some more advanced media types should be supported. As already mentioned by Cassio and Exadra37 there are a couple of JSON based document types that provide support for HATEOAS (~ URIs and link relation names). Instead of only going for i.e. [`application/hal+json`](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) a multitude of document types would be preferable as this just increases interoperablility with a magnitude of different clients that might come with support for other media types. Note futher that there is nothing wrong with returning a HTML representation as well. REST isn't restricting you to only specific JSON or XML content. I guess most of the time, instead of specifying an own media-type, simply using HTML would be sufficient to carry the meaning of the content from API to server.

You are of course free to create your own media type and use it. In order to increase interoperability you should however standardize it and probably also provide plugins/libraries for third party frameworks so that they are able to use your format as well.

The best advice, though, for sure is to reuse existing standards as the likelihood of other clients already being familiar with such implementations or concepts is way higher than for your custom format. Besides that, it probably also spares you from a lot of work and effort.

Comment: I really appreciate the complete and well-structured response. but unfortunately my team decided that the client should know how to generate the URL and the API should return only the alias, this way we can reduce the amount size of our API responses...